# Zoho sync data between crm and mysql

Tags: zoho

I am planning to use `zoho crm` for my business. On on side I have `clients` who pay my business, on other hand I have `online customer` to whom I assign work given to me by `clients`. So basically my business is kind a mediator.

Now I want to use `zoho crm` workflow automation like when lead is created signup mail should be sent. I want to increase lead score when client does particular activity. I want to use `webform` to capture leads.

My issue is that `zoho crm` gives very less number of APIs like 500 per user per day. Then how do I do capture leads directly into crm. How do I increase lead score.

How do you guys manage such scenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Calls per day day will depend of your subscription plan.

1. Standard: starts with 2000 calls per day
2. Professional: starts with 3000 per day
3. Enterprise: starts with 4000 per day

[Reference link](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/api-limits.html)

In several cases this will be enough, however there are a little tricks for saving API calls like using the API V4 in which you can insert/update multiples records (100 per request).

Also, you can use the custom function (zoho deluge) in the CRM and set yours workflow rules like:

Each time a new lead is created with the status "Not contacted" then:

1. Send a welcome email
2. Create a case (zoho deluge)
3. Create a taks (zoho deluge)
4. etc.

The rate limit for zoho custom functions is not the same as zoho api calls. (Integration Tasks - 25000 Zoho API calls/day using deluge.) So you can use both of them.

[Reference link](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/automation/custom-functions.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me toward Deluge. I am exploring deluge but didn't find much about "Integration Tasks". can you help me in understanding what are these.

Comment: "Integration tasks" is just another way to name "API functions" in Zoho Deluge.

Comment: Check this video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tqDHmdQR5eY&t=915s)

There you will see how to create your own function in deluge. The custom functions are located in Setup -> workflow -> custom functions

After you create a custom function, go to the Setup -> workflow and create a rule for testing, then relate a the custom function that you created.

Comment: Thanks @Cristian .